# Search for existence of specific children under a node

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am developing a chat app using **Firebase Realtime Database** and **Cloud Functions**. I have a node `members` where I store the IDs of each user in each chat room:

[image]

What I want to achieve (not efficiently so far) is to check if, for example, **user1** (with **randomUid1**) has an active chat with **user2** (with **randomUid2**) in the most efficient way possible. The only solution I have come up with is to download the whole node (`/members`) and check for every child of the datasnapshot, if the two `uids` are in presence. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are left with having to check them all. I dont think that will be a problem though as your chats are likely below 100k or so.

As I do not know the data structure you are using I am simply taking a stab at it based of your image and you have to adapt to your structure.

```
// assuming a reasonable structure
let chats = [{name: "chat1", "1": true, "5": true}, {name: "chat2", "1": true, "2": true}];

function hasChat(chats, uid1, uid2) {
    return chats.find((chat) => {
        let uids = Object.keys(chat);
        return uids.indexOf(uid1) !== -1 && uids.indexOf(uid2) !== -1;
    }) !== undefined;
}

console.log(hasChat(chats, "1", "2"));
```

This could be made more performant and more readable by using a library.

Comment: I don't want to use a library, so I think this is the best solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Following implementation works. But without indexing it will end up downloading everything under the `members` node, and filtering the data in the client:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref('members');
const snap1 = await ref.orderByChild('user1').equalTo(true).once('value');
const user1Chats = Object.keys(snap1.val());

const snap2 = await ref.orderByChild('user2').equalTo(true).once('value');
const user2Chats = Object.keys(snap2.val());

user1Chats.forEach((chat) => {
  if (user2Chats.indexOf(chat) >= 0) {
    console.log('Chat in common:', chat);
  }
});
```

The SDK will log the following warning:

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "user1" at /members to your security rules for better performance.
```

You can also try storing chats by each user (in addition to what you already have):

```
user1
  |
   -- chat1: true
   -- chat2: true

user2
  |
   -- chat2: true
   -- chat3: true
```

Then it's just a matter of querying the two user nodes, and checking if they have any overlap (chat2 in the above example). If the number of chatrooms in your app grows without bounds overtime, this solution will perform better in the long run. Hopefully the number of chats per user is much smaller than the total number of active chats in the entire app.

Comment: As for the first snippet, I will agree with you that it is not ideal. For your second proposition, I will try and see if it fits my current DB implementation and adjust it properly. Thank you!!